# Is the force vs position graph same as force vs displacement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, displacement

"Will the area under both the force vs. displacement curve and the force vs. position curve contribute to the total work done on the body? If so, I'm having trouble understanding why both of them contribute to the work. Are these two graphs essentially the same?"

Comment: Are position and displacement the same physical quantity?

Answer (score 0):

Position is not the same as displacement, so no, the force vs. position graph is not the same as force vs. displacement graph.